# How to prevent iOS tests from failing after changing orientation of simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a bunch of UI tests using OCUnit and OCMock, which run fine if the simulator is not up already or in Default (portrait). However, the same tests fail, if I start the tests with the simulator already up and in either of the Landscape orientations. The tests are run considering iPad is in default portrait. How do I prevent those tests from failing because the simulator is in another orientation?

My 2 options were.

1. Check if the orientation is Default portrait, if not skip those tests. This works, but doesn't seem to be very elegant.
2. Before the test, programmatically set the device orientation to Default portrait, which I'm not very sure of. I'm guessing this would also require a tearDown method to revert?

Comment: You are not telling us which framework you were using for your UI tests.

Comment: My bad, fixed it in the issue. OCMock it is.